# Datetime range selection javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I need to create a datetime range selector at the top of my dashboard such that, every chart and all text elements below gets filtered for the selected time period range.

So I was looking at this great solution by keith.
https://github.com/keithhackbarth/jquery-datetime-picker

I am a beginner in JS and there is nothing in the index.html for the above datetime picker.
There are only 4 JS libraries, which is too much code for a beginner.

I basically want to load the datetime as is there in my data only, so which part of code snippet do I start modifying?
Eg: The first column in my data - datetime is from 2014-03-01 to 2014-03-14
    So the datetime picker should show exactly that after reading my data(column here)

index.html code :

```
<input type="text" class="dt_date_start"/>
            <input type="text" class="dt_time_start" /> .........TO............
            <input type="text" class="dt_date_end" />
            <input type="text" class="dt_time_end" />
```

These are the four date ranges(classes) defined which are in datepair.js.

How do I go about editing datepair.js such that it loads the dates that I only want, which is present in the data.

Comment: The demos and examples are [**here**](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) and [**here**](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-datepair/) (you'll probably want _datepair_), your link seems to be just the UI mod for it

Comment: How and where exactly do I load my dataset for the daterange, that is still not clear to me.